# Geopandas Explore - Reorder Items in Legend

Tags: python, mapping, visualization, geopandas, folium

I'm working on plotting some Census data on a map using the Geopandas Explore method and am running into some issues with customizing the legend. For background, I've pulled together Household tract-level income data form the Census and created a household income classification column where I'm assigning one of 5 income categories to each tract. When I plot the dataset on a map, the legend seems to default to alphanumeric order which I'd like to override.

Here is my code:

```
hhi_gdf.explore(column='med_hh_inc_test',
                   cmap=['#2c7fb8','#a1dab4','#41b6c4','#253494','#ffffcc'],
                   tiles="CartoDB positron",
                   style_kwds={'opacity':.40,
                               'fillOpacity':.60},
                   legend_kwds={'caption':'Median Household Income'})
```

Here is the default result:
[default legend order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svFb8.jpg)

I've tried this to override the default legend order [the documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html) says you can override default legend by providing a dictionary to the legend_kwds param, specifying a  'list-like' list of legend labels to the 'labels' key which seems like the only way to change the legend labels at all.:

```
hhi_gdf.explore(column='med_hh_inc_test',
                   cmap=['#2c7fb8','#a1dab4','#41b6c4','#253494','#ffffcc'],
                   tiles="CartoDB positron",
                   style_kwds={'opacity':.40,
                               'fillOpacity':.60},
                   legend_kwds={'colorbar':False,
                                'caption':'Median Household Income',
                                'labels':[['Less than $45,000'],
                                         ['$45,000 - $74,999'],
                                         ['$75,000 - $124,999'],
                                         ['$125,000 - $199,999'],
                                         ['Greater than $200,000']]})
```

Here is the resulting plot (no difference in legend order):
[no change in legend order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOVEj.jpg)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. This is an awesome method if only it was a little easier to customize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible using the public API as the order is hard-coded in the code. But you can try using the private function that creates the legend to get the desired outcome. Just try not to rely on it in a long-term. I'll open an issue on this in GeoPandas to implement this kind of customisation directly there.

```py
from geopandas.explore import _categorical_legend

m = hhi_gdf.explore(
    column='med_hh_inc_test',
    cmap=['#2c7fb8','#a1dab4','#41b6c4','#253494','#ffffcc'],
    tiles="CartoDB positron",
    style_kwds={'opacity':.40,'fillOpacity':.60},
    legend=False
)
_categorical_legend(
    m, 
    title="Median Household Income", 
    categories=[
        "Less than $45,000",
        "$45,000 - $74,999",
        "$75,000 - $124,999",
        "$125,000 - $199,999",
        "Greater than $200,000"],
    colors=['#2c7fb8','#a1dab4','#41b6c4','#253494','#ffffcc']
)
m
```

You may need to do some shuffling with cmap to ensure it is all properly mapped.

Comment: This worked! Thank you for your help - I'd been messing with this for hours, I never thought to use the private function. I left the order of the colors the same in 'cmap', but changes the order for the list provided to the colors param.

Comment: Wondering if perhaps cmap or another param could accept a list of lists or maybe a dictionary to specify the order of legend items?

`cmap = [["Less than $45,000",'#ffffcc'],["$45,000 - $74,999",'#a1dab4'],["$75,000 - $124,999",'#41b6c4'],["$125,000 - $199,999",'#2c7fb8'],["Greater than $200,000",'#253494']]

cmap = {{"Less than $45,000":'#ffffcc'},{"$45,000 - $74,999":'#a1dab4'},{"$75,000 - $124,999":'#41b6c4'},{"$125,000 - $199,999":'#2c7fb8'},{"Greater than $200,000":'#253494'}}`

Comment: Yes, a dict mapping values to colors has been discussed and will likely be supported in future, but I can't promise any timeline.